# Vue.js transition stagger not working

Tags: javascript, css, transition, vue.js

I am trying to get a list rendered with `v-for` to stagger its build in per the Vuejs docs. I'm using the `stagger` attribute and firing a `Vue.nextTick` flag to get the transition to fire just after `ready` triggers. Not sure if I'm missing something. Using Vue 1.0.26. Any ideas?

Demo: http://codepen.io/thelucre/pen/WGQaPd

Docs: http://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html#Staggering-Transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The staggered transitions will only fire when the data for the `v-for` directive actually changes, not in the case of `v-show` or `v-if`. In my case then, I'll be using a computed property that holds an empty array and then sets the data after the `nextTick()` function call.

Updated demo: http://codepen.io/thelucre/pen/WGQaPd

Answer source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3658#issuecomment-246256099

Answer (score -1):

Is [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjpaNg) what you're after?

Your transition attribute was set to fade.

```
<div v-if="show" v-for="item in items" transition="fade" stagger="1000" class="item">{{ item }}</div>
```

I changed it to staggered and copied the CSS from the example in the docs.

Comment: In this case, the transitions are still firing at the same time, it just appears staggered because they're all animating height. I'm answering my own question based on a response to a Github issue.